# Can the analytic arc of an irred. $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$-character always be lifted to an analytic arc of an irred. representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, 3-manifolds, character-varieties

Is there an example of an irreducible and boundary irreducible $3$-manifold $M$ with torus boundary and a non-abelian representation $\rho: \pi_1(M) \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, a non-constant analytic arc $\chi_t$ of irreducible representations with endpoint at $\chi_{\rho}$ in the $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ character variety $X(M)$ of $\pi_1(M)$, satisfying the condition:

- for every infinite sequence $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n,\cdots\}$ of elements $u_i\in Z^1(\pi_1(M),Ad_{\rho})$, the expression
  $$\rho_t=\exp(u_1 t+ u_2 t^2+ \cdots + u_n t^n +\cdots) \rho$$
  does not define a lift of $\chi_t$  in $\overline {R(M)^{irr}} \subset \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(M),\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C}))$.

Comment: The first sentence of your question is difficult to parse -- you might consider splitting it into shorter sentences.

Comment: You might have a look at Fine, Kirk, and Klassen, A local analytic splitting of the holonomy map on flat connections. Math. Ann. 299 (1994), no. 1, 171–189.